# Fullcalendar event recurring end time incorrect

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

I am facing an issue to do weekly or daily recurring event using FullCalendar. On my appointment slot for daygrid. The end time for the slot is incorrect. It should appeared from `11:45:00` to `16:45:00` but the actual result i get from the view is displaying from`11:45:00` to `12:45:00`.

```
events.push({
  id: value.id,
  resourceId: value.user_id,
  rrule: {
    freq: 'weekly',
    byweekday: ['mo', 'tu', 'we', 'th'],
    dtstart: value.start_date + ' ' + value.start_time, //current value: 2020-06-03 11:45:00
    until: value.end_date + ' ' + value.end_time //current value: 2020-06-30 16:45:00
  }
  display: 'background',
  exdate: ['2021-06-03']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `until` date specifies when the whole recurrence period should end. It does not specify the length of each individual event.

The [fullCalendar Rrule documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) mentions the `duration` property which you can specify in order to do that:

> **duration**
> Must be something that parses into a Duration. If not
> specified, each event will appear to have the default duration

11.45 - 16.45 is 5 hours, so if you set

```
duration: "05:00"
```

as a property of the event, then this will have the desired effect.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEerKJJ